# Your system does not have Meson installed when compiling HelenOS

Tags: ubuntu, operating-system

I am trying to compile HelenOS in Ubuntu but when I do the command "../../helenos/configure.sh amd64" it will give me an error saying I do not have Meson installed even though I do. I hope you can help and if this helps here is the links to HelenOS

https://github.com/HelenOS/helenos

The OS was meant to compile even with Meson installed

Comment: When it says you don't have Meson installed, it means it can't find Meson in the typical places.  Where did you install Meson?  You'll need to point configure to include that path ... don't know which flag it'd be though.

Comment: Hey, I figured it out thank you for the response, but I need help again, I'm going to make changes to the code for HelenOS, to compile you have to do ninja, but when I make a change and execute ninja it will just say "ninja: no work to do", I'm not too sure how your recompile it again